# User database design for marketplace-style app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

Need some best-practice wisdom as I'm new to database architecture. This is for a marketplace type app. The main issue I'd like advice on is handling users.

What I'd like to achieve is buyer and seller accounts share login/signup functionality and some characteristics, but seller accounts have the ability to sell, receive payments, etc. Buyers can send requests, sellers can complete them. Basically a seller can do everything a buyer can do, but additionally view and fulfill requests, and sell.

I'd go with simple roles, except sellers have more complex relationships than buyers in terms of products and payment info. Also sellers need to be able to be publicly listed, and have public profiles. I'm not sure that having 1 big table with both users types would be ideal for this.

My current idea is to use polymorphic associations between a base User table and a seller table (potentially a buyer specific table as well):

### User (buyer)

- name
- email
- encrypted_password
- (other authentication fields)
- location
- occupation
- meta_id
- meta_type

### Seller

- name
- location
- occupation
- etc

### requests (belongs to buyer and seller)

- type
- description
- complete
- buyer_id
- seller_id

### products (belongs to seller)

- description
- category_id
- seller_id

As you can see, a big issue is that fact that buyers and sellers have duplicate data. The reason for this is because when I'm displaying sellers I don't want to have to perform multi-table queries, but maybe that's not an issue? Another option would be to have the User base table and then buyer and seller tables, but they'd still contain duplicate info.

Open to all possibilities.. What's the best way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent this kind of relationship using database supertypes and subtypes.

For your example, I would split the data model into two groups: *users* and *roles*. A role can be either a buyer or a seller, and a user can have zero or more roles.

I would then create the following logical entities to represent the *role* relationship:

**Supertype**

- UserRole (this name is likely to be too generic; I would suggest a name that better reflects the role of both the buyer and the seller within your application).

**Subtypes**

- Buyer
- Seller

For your physical design, I would suggest one of the following designs:

1. A single table that contains the columns for the supertype entity as well as columns for each of the subtype entities. Check constraints can be used to enforce not-null constraints for the subtype columns.
2. One table for the supertype, with a separate table for each subtype entity. Columns that are common to each subtype are stored in the supertype table, with the other columns stored in the appropriate subtype table. A type column is added to the supertype table to indicate the type of the entity. Each subtype table includes a foreign key relationship to the supertype table.
3. Hybrid approach that combines aspects from each of the above designs.

**Access Patterns**

One factor to consider when deciding how to model a subtype and supertype relationship is whether your queries will need to access columns from both the supertype and the subtype tables. If most of your queries will access columns from the supertype and subtype tables, then a single table may be a better design.

**Edit -** I would suggest using the first design, unless there is a compelling reason to create separate tables for the subtypes. Foreign keys that include the type column can be used to restrict relationships to a particular subtype.

**Mapping a user to a role**

To assign a user to a role, you can simply create a many-to-many relationship between the User table and the supertype (UserRole) table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like design #2, that's what I've been thinking of doing, but my biggest hangup is the access patterns. Both buyers and sellers have a 'name'. If I store this in UserRole whenever I access either a buyer or seller I have to get UserRole to know the name. The biggest problem would be when listing sellers and on their profile pages. Querying multiple tables would seem like it would impact performance and be bad design, but if the alternative is duplicating data then I'm not sure. Thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest going with the first design. Your queries will be simpler to write and will perform better than they would against the second design, since you will not need to join the subtype table to the supertype table. If you do decide to use the second design, you could create an indexed view between the supertype table and a subtype table to improve performance for queries that need to access all columns. I wouldn't worry about NULL values for subtype columns in the first design; not-null constraints can be applied using CHECK constraints.

Comment: ...but if the alternative is duplicating data then I'm not sure.... Other than the primary key value of the supertype entity, you would not need to store duplicate data in any of the subtype tables. Common columns would only be stored in the supertype table. If you decided to create separate tables for the subtypes, then the tables would only need to contain columns that are specific to the subtype.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about **polymorphism** ?

You can create a 'mother' class `User` (with [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for example) and create two 'children' classes `Buyer` and `Seller` !

Good tutorial [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/back-to-basics-polymorphism-and-ruby)

Comment: Yes, that was my exact thought:

_My current idea is to use polymorphic associations between a base User table and a seller table (potentially a buyer specific table as well)._

Comment: Oh okay ! I just used it on a project here [pinkpanda/skeria](https://github.com/pinkpanda/skeria/tree/develop/app/models). Check `Admins`, `Collaborators`, `Clients` and `User (from Devise)`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing all users are either buyer|seller but not both, I would do the following, which I think is basically what you were proposing:

PERSON
  // I would actually have a ROLE table and only include role_id in PERSON table but that may not add anything except complexity for you, it depends if there are data about the different roles that you would like to store in the db

SELLER
person_id

BUYER
person_id
 // Maybe there aren't any additional data for BUYERS, but if you are going to implement database-level foreign key constraints then populating this table will allow you constrain on an actual BUYER

and then the additional tables. If you are using foreign key constraints for data integrity, then you would constrain buyer_id & seller_id on the specific tables (BUYER,SELLER) which guarantees you more than simply constraining on PERSON.

In case people can be both a buyer and seller, then I would probably still go with this model and have a role BUYER_AND_SELLER but it may be preferable to add columns is_buyer and is_seller to PERSON in case you are confident these are the only roles you will ever support.

Comment: Ideally, a user could be a buyer and seller at the same time with the more common scenario of being just a buyer. With this model I could place shared data (name for example) in the Person table, which I like but when I am listing sellers I have to query both the seller table and the person table to get all the necessary seller info. Thoughts?

Comment: Well, when you want all data for a particular user you will join the tables in your query, so you'll perform one query that pulls the data out of multiple tables (you could join PERSON/BUYER and PERSON/SELLER or perhaps PERSON/BUYER/SELLER if that works better for your needs).  So long as you index person_id and the foreign key references appropriately the performance impact should be negligible. It might make sense to create views that hide the join from the data users and logically present all BUYER data in one view and all SELLER data in another.